# Derivative of a function and Christoffel symbols

Tags: differential-geometry

I wonder if I can simplify the third derivative with respect to $u_k$ of the expression:
\begin{align} 
 \frac{\partial^2 k}{\partial u_l\partial u_j}(u, \lambda, a) =
 2\left({{\sum_{i=0}^{n}}}{\lambda_i}\frac{\partial^2 x_i(u)}{\partial u_l\partial u_j}\right) +\left({{\sum_{i=0}^{n}}}  \gamma N_i\frac{\partial^2 x_i(u)}{\partial u_l u_j}\right) 
 \label{primeiraesegundaformafundamental}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
 \frac{\partial^3 k}{\partial u_l \partial u_j \partial u_k}(u, \lambda, a)=2 \sum_{i=0}^n \lambda_i \frac{\partial^3 x_i(u)}{\partial u_l \partial u_j \partial u_k}&\
 +2 \sum_{i=0}^n \gamma \frac{\partial^2 x_i(u)}{\partial u_l \partial u_j}\frac{\partial N_i}{\partial u_k}\
 & \\ \nonumber+2 \sum_{i=0}^n \gamma N_i \frac{\partial^3 x_i(u)}{\partial u_l \partial u_j \partial u_k}
\end{align}

$N$ is the normal vector of a hypersurface, and $\gamma$ and $\lambda_i$ are constants for each $i$. I tried but I didn't see any interesting relation between the derivative of the normal with the second derivatives of the hypersurface. Maybe Christoffel symbols? What I hope I get is a nice relation between $\gamma$ and all the $\lambda_i$ when setting all the second and third partial derivatives to zero.

Comment: I don't see why you're separating the RHS into two sums. Where did this come from, and what are the third derivatives supposed to tell you?

Comment: I'm actually trying to find a relation between $\gamma$ and $\lambda$ when setting both derivatives equals 0.

Comment: By the way, I just noticed that indices don’t make sense. On the left, $j$ is fixed, but on the right you’ve summed over all $j$. What do you intend to say? And explain what “setting both derivatives equal to $0$” means.

Comment: Hi Ted, you're right... I edited the question.

Comment: Christoffel symbols play a role in **covariant** derivatives on a **Riemannian** manifolds. Why would you expect them to play a role here?